# Filter ggplot2 density plot by number of observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to filter out subsets of the data that have small numbers of observations within a ggplot2 call?

For example, take the following plot: `qplot(price,data=diamonds,geom="density",colour=cut)`

[image: Density plot]

The plot is a little busy, and I would like the exclude the `cut` values with a small number of observations, ie,

```
> xtabs(~cut,diamonds)
cut
     Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
     1610      4906     12082     13791     21551
```

the `Fair` and `Good` qualities of the `cut` factor.

I'm wanting a solution that can fit an arbitrary data set and if possible be able to select not just by a threshold number of observations, but by top 3 for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ggplot(subset(diamonds, cut %in% arrange(count(diamonds, .(cut)), desc(freq))[1:3,]$cut),
  aes(price, colour=cut)) + 
  geom_density() + facet_grid(~cut)
```

1. `count` counts up each elements into data.frame.
2. `arrange` orders a data.frame based on the specified column.
3. `desc` enables reversed-order sorting.
4. finally subset the rows whose cut is included in the top 3 by `%in%`.

Comment: missing droplevels() but like the use of %in% +1

Comment: Yes. so, droplevels(subset(...)) is correct if you want to draw the legend of unused factors. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. There are so many good answers, but I decided to give this the tick as the most "internal" ggplot solution to the problem. I thought that there may have been a `..nobservations..` variable to access, or some manipulation using `stat_sum`, but this way of subsetting is more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take. First make a function that returns the categories with more obs.

```
firstx <- function (category, data, x = 1:3) {
  tab <- xtabs(~category, data)

  dimnames(tab)$category[order(tab, decreasing = TRUE)[x]]
}

#Then use subset to subset the data and droplevels to drop unused levels
#so they don't clutter the legend.
ggplot(droplevels(subset(diamonds, cut %in% firstx(cut, diamonds))), 
       aes(price, color = cut)) + geom_density()
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to call for writing your own subsetting function, perhaps something like this:

```
mySubset <- function(dat,largestK=3,thresh=NULL){
   if (is.null(thresh)){
      tbl <- sort(table(dat)) 
      return(dat %in% tail(names(tbl),largestK))
   }
   else{
      return(dat >= thresh)
   }
}
```

That could be used in the ggplot call like this:

```
ggplot(diamonds[mySubset(diamonds$cut),],...)
```

This code doesn't deal with dropping levels from factors, so watch out for that. I usually leave categorical variables as characters for that reason, unless I absolutely need them to be ordered.

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected. You can drop levels by refactoring cut in the `colour` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
## Top 3 cuts
tmp <- names(sort(summary(diamonds$cut), decreasing = T))[1:3]
tmp <- droplevels(subset(diamonds, cut == tmp))
ggplot(tmp, aes(price, color=cut)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

But have you considered faceting?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, color=cut)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(~cut)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brandon, but I've got quite a number of factor levels in the data I'm using, so I'm really wanting a method that selects only the most numerous ones, otherwise space and clarity become an issue.

Comment: In your question you wrote top3 but you specified Fair and Good which were bottom2. If it was the latter, remove decreasing = T and change [1:3] to [1:2] in my solution

Comment: Its unclear because I put the xtabs output in the middle of the sentence, but I wanted to exclude Fair and Good. Your new solution works as expected though, thanks!